# Angularjs getting data from controller scope to directive scope

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to get data from resource then add it to isolate scope of directive but when i want to print it to screen i get error as undefined current_page here is the script

```
/**
     * Created by yigit on 10.01.2014.
     */
    var app = angular.module('kategori', [
        'ngResource',
        'apiBaseRoute'
    ]);

    app.factory('Data', ['$resource', 'apiBaseRoute', function($resource, config){
        return $resource(config.apiBasePath + 'kategori/?page=:page',{page:1},{
            query:{
                isArray: false,
                method: 'GET'
            }
        });
    }]);

    app.controller('KategoriListCtrl',['$scope', 'Data', function($scope, Data){

        $scope.allData = {data:null};
        Data.query({}, function(data){
            $scope.kategoriList = {data:data.cat.data};
            $scope.allData.data = data.cat;
        });
    }]);
    app.directive('paginate', function(){
        return{
            scope:{paginatorData: '=paginate'},
            link: function(scope){
                alert(scope.paginatorData.current_page);
            }
        }
    });



<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html ng-app="kategori">
            <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <title></title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
            </head>
            <body>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" ng-controller="KategoriListCtrl">
            {{allData.current_page}}
                <div paginate="allData"></div>
            </div>

            <script src="js/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/lib/angular-resource.js"></script>
            <script src="js/kategori.js"></script>
            <script src="js/apiroute.js"></script>
            </body>
            </html>
```

I read this article [nested scope](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/14/nested-scopes-in-angularjs.html)

But could not solve my problem.

So, the code alerts undefined. How can i solve this?

Comment: Try to add controller property to your direcrive and set scope as parameter like you have in link

Comment: how? im really noob thanks.

Comment: Where do you set `current_page`?

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your HTML? You'll need to pass the property like this:

```
<div data-paginate="paginate"></div>
```